# Why is ASP.NET Core setting cache-control headers on error responses?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-web-api, cache-control

`startup.cs`

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
            });
        });
        services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseResponseCaching();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

`TestController.cs`

```cs
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 60)]
    [HttpGet("/fail")]
    public IActionResult Fail()
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

When I hit the `/fail` endpoint, it returns a 400 status as expected but it has a `Cache-Control` header of `public,max-age=60` because of the `ResponseCache` attribute on the action method. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configuration),

> Response Caching Middleware only caches server responses that result in a 200 (OK) status code. Any other responses, including error pages, are ignored by the middleware.

How can I stop error responses (or any non-200 response) from being cached?

Comment: The note you've quoted refers to the response-caching middleware not caching the full response server-side. The `ResponseCacheFilter`, which runs as an MVC action filter, doesn't appear to take the status-code into consideration when setting the caching headers.

Comment: @KirkLarkin true, and thanks for the info. I wasn’t originally using the response caching middleware, I only added that while trying to fix the issue. So how do people usually get around this problem then? They just accept that browsers will cache any error responses? If the errors are transient, a browser refresh might fix the problem, but not if it’s caching error responses.

Answer (score 4):

The `ResponseCacheFilter` ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Filters/ResponseCacheFilter.cs)) is the action filter that actually sets the `Cache-Control` headers, but it doesn't take into account status codes, so it's not actually possible to do what I wanted.

Instead, I wrote my own action filter:

```cs
public class CacheControlAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int Duration { get; set; } = 0;

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (ResultIsSuccess(context.Result))
        {
            SetCacheControlHeaders(context.HttpContext.Response);
        }
    }

    private bool ResultIsSuccess(IActionResult result)
    {
        return result is IStatusCodeActionResult statusCodeActionResult && statusCodeActionResult.StatusCode is >= 200 and < 300;
    }

    private void SetCacheControlHeaders(HttpResponse response)
    {
        response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = $"public,max-age={Duration}";
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [CacheControl(Duration = 60)]
    [HttpGet("/fail")]
    public IActionResult Fail()
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

It will only set the `Cache-Control` headers on success status codes (>= 200 and < 300).

Also, no need for the `app.UseResponseCaching()` middleware in either case, as it doesn't control the `Cache-Control` headers; it just reads them (as might be set by the `ResponseCache` attribute), and caches cacheable responses to implement server-side caching.