# ResponseCache attribute causing non 200 responses to be cached

Tags: asp.net-core

We are using the [ResponseCacheAttribute] from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core with a policy like so on action methods or controllers:

```
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Default")]
```

In case a non 200 response is send like 400, 403 or 500 it is also being cached. So the first time we go to the server and get for example bad request. The second time no call is made to the server and the answer is still bad request (from disk cache).
I read in the documentation that when using response cache middleware only 200 responses are being cached. This attribute seems to be flawed and always adds the caching response header no matter what status code.

We like to define caching only on certain controllers or action methods. Not on all requests.

Does anyone know the solution for this?

I simulate the problem by using a status code result:

```
  return StatusCode(500);
```

I would then expect it to always come back to this code with a breakpoint and never caching it.

Comment: have you added the `[Authorize]` attribute to your controller?

Comment: No, I haven't add [Authorize].  [ApiController] public class RefController : ControllerBase

Comment: it seems like since the `Controller`  or `Action` is  not Authorized the `Action` response is cached. try adding the `[Authorize]` to you `Controller`  or `Action`

Comment: We are using a custom company (security) framework where we are not allowed to use [Authorize]

Comment: so at what level does the authoriazation check happens? inside the `Action` ? `middleware`?

Comment: Middleware i think. I didn't work on that framework.

Comment: so if the middleware authenticates, then how can you reach the `Action` and get `403`? impossible ryt?

Comment: 403 was just an example, I simulate it by doing for example
return StatusCode(500);  or return StatusCode(403);

Comment: seems like the question need more insight

Comment: I changed the description a bit to make it not look like an issue with authentication.

Comment: Could you please share how have you configured cache for your perticular controller? Usually, we can use [`ResponseCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-7.0#vary) attribute for implementing caching on certain controllers. You can [`have a look the sample here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-7.0#vary)

Comment: This is a clear question, matches my what I am looking for, and google search found it.  Disagree with @thanzeel about needing insight.  Too bad no answer yet..  Started with the link to MS and did not glean answer there in 5 min of scanning.  Edit: Found this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901155/why-is-asp-net-core-setting-cache-control-headers-on-error-responses#answer-67918994